# How prove $\left(1+\frac{4a}{b+c}\right)\left(1+\frac{4b}{c+a}\right)\left(1+\frac{4c}{a+b}\right)\ge 25$

Tags: inequality

let $a,b,c>0$ show that
$$\left(1+\dfrac{4a}{b+c}\right)\left(1+\dfrac{4b}{c+a}\right)\left(1+\dfrac{4c}{a+b}\right)\ge 25$$

It seem hard to prove AM-GM.Cauchy-Schwarz

Comment: Are $a,b,c$ real numbers or integers?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

On full expansion, this reduces to a combination of Schur's inequality $\sum a^3 +3abc\geqslant \sum ab(a+b)$ and $abc>0$, so the inequality is in fact strict.

Answer (score 0):

$$\Leftrightarrow a^{3}+b^3+c^3+7abc\geq ab(a+b)+bc(b+c)+ca(c+a) > 0$$

Right by Schur: 
$$a^{3}+b^3+c^3+7abc> a^{3}+b^3+c^3+3abc\geq ab(a+b)+bc(b+c)+ca(c+a)$$